# Calling a ruby script using a shell command fails at 'load_rakefile'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, rake, shoes

I have run into a problem with using a shell command that calls a Ruby script, which then invokes Rake.

I have built a test automation framework that does the following when run from the command line (I'm on OSX Yosemite):

1. Calls a Ruby script which sets a bunch of Environment Variables
2. It then invokes Rake

   ```
   rake = Rake.application
   rake.init
   rake.load_rakefile
   rake['execute_tests'].invoke
   ```
3. The Rake file runs a Cucumber Task and the test framework then happily launches a browser and starts executing tests.

   ```
   Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:execute_tests) do |task|
       # => need to populate these so that the cucumber.yml parses
       ENV['TEST_WEB_PARALLEL_OS'] = "null"
       ENV['TEST_WEB_PARALLEL_OS_VERSION'] = "null"
       ENV['TEST_WEB_PARALLEL_BROWSER'] = "null"
       ENV['TEST_WEB_PARALLEL_BROWSER_VERSION'] = "null"

       #------------------------------------------------
       # Specify rake profile
       #------------------------------------------------
       runProfile = ENV['TEST_PLATFORM'].downcase + "_" + ENV['TEST_INTERFACE'].downcase + "_" + ENV['TEST_ENVIRONMENT'].downcase + "_" + ENV['TEST_TYPE'].downcase
       # => running headless
       if ENV['TEST_HEADLESS'] == "TRUE"
          # => need to truncate poltergeist - using the @poltergeist tag in cucumber was causing issues with other drivers
          ENV['TEST_BROWSER'] = "POLTER"
          reportProfile = ENV['TEST_PLATFORM'].downcase + "_" +  ENV['TEST_INTERFACE'].downcase + "_" + ENV['TEST_ENVIRONMENT'].downcase + "_" + ENV['TEST_TYPE'].downcase + "_" + osHelper.getOperatingSystem.to_s + "_" + ENV['TEST_BROWSER'].downcase + "_hlst"
       # => running headed
       else
           reportProfile = ENV['TEST_PLATFORM'].downcase + "_" + ENV['TEST_INTERFACE'].downcase + "_" + ENV['TEST_ENVIRONMENT'].downcase + "_" + ENV['TEST_TYPE'].downcase + "_" + osHelper.getOperatingSystem.to_s + "_" + ENV['TEST_BROWSER'].downcase + "_lst"
       end

       #------------------------------------------------
       # Set the env var then run profile
       #------------------------------------------------
       ENV['REPORT_PROFILE'] = reportProfile
       ENV['RUN_PROFILE'] = runProfile
       task.profile = runProfile
   end
   ```

This all works perfectly well when I execute from the command line. The problem is that I want to put a basic GUI on the front of the test framework. I am using Shoe3 to do this.

When I call my initial Ruby script from the GUI...

```
`ruby ./exe/execute_web_tests_local_singlethread.rb salesforce integration regression headed chrome false false`
```

...then the code executes until the point where the following line tries to execute:

```
rake.load_rakefile
```

At this the code fails over. I don't see any output or stacktrace from the sub-process so am unable to debug beyond the point of knowing that the process falls over at the line specified above.

[Screenshot of GUI failing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEfrJ.png)

Unfortunately that's as specific as I can be. If anybody could provide any pointers for how I might go about investigating and/or resolving this issue it would be much appreciated.

I have tried using Open3 as well, this has resulted in the same issue.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

When you shell out to Ruby with `ruby ./exe/execute_web_tests_local_singlethread.rb`, the child process will run in the current working directory of the parent process (i.e. the one your GUI application is running from).

When `rake.load_rakefile` is called, it will be looking for the `Rakefile` relative to the current working directory, *not* the directory relative to the script you're calling out to.

There's a couple of ways you can fix this. One is by setting the `RAKEOPT` environment variable in the parent process (your GUI) *before* you execute the command. This will be inherited by the child process:

```
ENV['RAKEOPT'] = "--rakefile ./exe/Rakefile"
```

Alternatively, you can change the working directory in the parent process:

```
Dir.chdir("./exe") do
  `ruby execute_web_tests_local_singlethread.rb salesforce integration regression headed chrome false false`
end
```

This might not be advisable. If your application is threaded and relying on the current directory (and Shoes may be), you might have some unexpected consequences modifying the current directory.

One last thing: you may not be able to start up a child process that runs a a browser in this way. Both full browsers and headless browsers, to the best of my knowledge, need information about the graphical environment you're running in. This is fine when you're running a process attached to a GUI terminal session, but you might run into other issues trying to spin up another graphical process from inside Shoes.

Hope that helps!